# Wiring and soldering a prototype board for a Pi Zero

Tags: gpio

I want to go from breadboard to a prototype board for my Raspberry Pi project and I wanted to get some advice on my approach.
Here is a Fritzing image of my diagram. This is the first time I've put one together, so there's probably something wrong with the diagram, but the actual breadboard/cobbler/Pi combination works.

[image: Fritzing wiring diagram]

I plan on soldering male headers to the Pi Zero and a female header to the prototype board. To wire the connections between the MCP3008 and the corresponding GPIO pins on the female header, I planned to connect the pad next to the needed GPIO header with some solder and then solder a wire to that pad. I would repeat that same process for the MCP3008 to complete the connection. Does that sound right?

Also, based on the diagram, could I connect a ground line on the other side of the cobbler to the ground on the breadboard so I wouldn't have run ground connections across the MCP3008? I think the answer is yes, I haven't touched this thing in months since I got it to work. Since I am completely new to this, I hesitate to mess with what works.

Answer (score 1):

"I hesitate to mess with what works"

That being said, are you aware that there are solder boards that are the same layout as the prototype breadboards so that you can transfer your working design directly? For example [Radio Shack part # 276-0170](https://www.radioshack.com/collections/breadboards-ic-sockets/products/radioshack-printed-circuit-board) if you can get there before your local store goes out of business.

You might have to do a minor adjustment on your power bus connections but shouldn't be hard to run all the positives down one side and the grounds down the other.

It ain't pretty but it'll work.

p.s. Just in case you're too late, [Mouser carries one too](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/BusBoard-Prototype-Systems/SB830/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMuwa3xtPTB8CzEcmWINKSpq13iiDGDxQ9A%3D) and it has the two busses on either side, exactly like your prototype.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I appreciate it. I realize I left it out of the original post, but I need to use the prototype outside, so I was hoping to get it to a more manageable size and fit it inside of a case. Otherwise, I would go the route you proposed.

Comment: Those solderboards come in half size, too. Your circuit uses a lot of space for that T-connector. Perhaps consider the half-size solderboard, eliminate the T-connector and hook up directly between Pi and your card. Look on eBay for Dupont cables M-F or F-F. These come all attached together but you can peel a few off and they will plug nicely onto the GPIO header, then solder the other end to your circuit.